# How to calculate the percentage of values greater than 0 in PromQL (Prometheus)

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql

Please, can somebody explain to me how to get percentage of values greater than 0 in PromQL.

I know that i can get vector values greater than 0 with this: `TS_VEC>0`.
[image]

I think i need something like `count_over_time(TS_VEC>0[24h])/{count_over_time(TS_VEC[24h])}` but it's not work.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following query returns per each time series `m` the estimated percentage of raw samples greater than 0 during the last day:

```
avg_over_time(
  (m >bool 0)[1d:10s]
) * 100
```

This query works in the following way:

1. It selects all the time series with the name `m` over the last day. You can use any needed  [series selector](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/keyConcepts.html#filtering) instead of `m`.
   This query uses [subquery feature](https://prometheus.io/blog/2019/01/28/subquery-support/).
2. It generates `24h/10s=8640` points per each selected time series from raw samples over the last 24 hours according to [this algorithm](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#staleness).
3. It substitutes point values from step 2, which are bigger than 0 with 1, while replacing remaining point values with 0 according to `>bool` comparison. See [these docs](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#comparison-binary-operators) for details.
4. It calculates the average value over points returned from step 3, individually per each selected time series. See [avg_over_time docs](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#avg_over_time).
   The average value 0 means that the original time series has no values bigger than 0 during the last 24 hours. The average value 1 means that all the values for a particular time series are bigger than 0 during the last 24 hours.
5. It multiplies the average value per each matxhing time series by 100 in order to get the percentage of raw samples bigger than 0 over the last 24 hours.

P.S. The query can be simplified to the following one when using [VictoriaMetrics](https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/VictoriaMetrics/) - the Prometheus-like monitoring solution I work on:

```
share_gt_over_time(m[1d], 0) * 100
```

See [share_gt_over_time() docs](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#share_gt_over_time).

Comment: thank you very much for your answer and examples.  Your solution is works perfectly for my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

`count(TS_VEC>0)/count(TS_VEC)`

Comment: thank you for your answer! But it's not working, got no data response with this query.